# Task Management Options

Tags: c#, task

I have a need in an application for task management and was looking for open source or third party customizable software that has a robust API that I can plug in.  Platform is .Net but willing to look outside of that platform if needed.  Any suggestions because I rather not reinvent the wheel and build it.

Comment: Please clarify "task management".  Would this be managing a series of tasks, e.g. a workflow?

Comment: What kind of tasks do you mean? Running processes on your computer and something like Windows Task Manager, or day-to-day tasks and project administration?

Comment: This sounds similar to a question I asked recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837247/which-tool-technology-system-management-for-databases-and-dependent-services maybe psake would be a solution for you.

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear.  When I say task management I mean managing tasks in workflow fashion.  Like help desk software where tasks get created and are routed and worked until completed.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I am related to Eylean development

Try agile task board [www.eylean.com](http://www.eylean.com) it is feature richt with outlook and tfs integration, excel import/export and many more cool features alongside beatifully handcrafted user interface.

[image]

Comment: you should disclose your connection to www.eylean.com

Comment: Sorry, added a disclaimer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for pre-built powerful extensible functionality then checkout [SharePoint.](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/Pages/default.aspx)  Plugging in and extending the API can be a bit challenging, but its got great default functionality, a powerful web designer, and powerful - configureable workflows.  I lived with the Microsoft [SharePoint book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321718313) by my side, it has details that you will not find on MSDN that often are critical to achieving your goals (I had the 2007 edition, but I'm sure the 2010 is gonna be great too).

On the other hand (or dont have a few grand in the budget), you can go straight to the [WF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx) framework and customize to your heart's extent.  Once again, from my firsthand experience this framework is also challenging, but the basics can be easily accomplished in visual studio with a nice design based drag-drop UI.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [AgileZen](http://www.agilezen.com).  It is web-based, and I know they have an API.  I use it for my home projects and love it.  It is an agile-based Kanban board system.

Answer (score -1):

[Pivotal Tracker](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/) is an online project management tool. It's not very customizable, but they seem to have a proper [REST-based API](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/api?version=v3). So you can use any platform you want.

I don't have much experience with other applications, so I can't suggest any others.